# catch all fatal errors in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, fatal-error

is there a way to catch all fatal errors on rails - in the controllers or in the view.

So far i tried to do this on application controller:

```
before_filter :catch_all_errors

def catch_all_errors
  rescue Exception
  logger.info "Catch exception"
end
```

And it doesn't work, the fatal errors generated by rails still ends up on the log file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have always used the [exception_logger plugin](https://github.com/defunkt/exception_logger). You will get a small page with all logged exceptions. This is super useful when your site goes online, but you want to know about problems with your app.

Comment: actually does fatal error counts as an exception? Can you catch a fatal error?